# Python: create permutation of variables and operators

Tags: python, permutation

It's about a quite simple dice game with the following rules:

1. Chose a number between 1 and 100
2. Role three dices at once
3. Get as close as possible to the chosen number with the rolled points and the following options:

   - addition, subtraction, multiplication and/or
   - multiply the points with 10

Example 1:

```
Dice1 = 2, Dice2 = 3, Dice3 = 1, Chosen number = 5

Possible calculations:           
         2 + 3 * 1 = 5 or 
         2 * 3 - 1 = 5
```

Example 2:

```
Dice1 = 6, Dice2 = 2, Dice3 = 2, Chosen number = 42

Possible calculation:
         (6*10) - (2*10) + 2 = 42
```

Goal of my program is to find the best possible ways for combining points and operators.

What I have so far:

```
import sys
import operator

a = int (sys.argv[1])   # Dice 1
b = int (sys.argv[2])   # Dice 2
c = int (sys.argv[3])   # Dice 3
d = int (sys.argv[4])   # Number to reach

class Calc():

    def __init__(self):
        self.resultsdict = dict()
        self.werte = dict()
        permutations = [[a,b,c], [a,c,b], [b,a,c], [b,c,a], [c,a,b], [c,b,a]]
        for p in permutations:
            aa = int(p[0])
            bb = int(p[1])
            cc = int(p[2])
            self.compute(aa,bb,cc, d)
        self.getBest(d, a, b, c)

    def compute(self, a,b,c,d):
        func = [a+b+c, a+b-c, a+b*c, (a+b)*c, (a-b)+c, a-(b+c), a-b-c, a-b*c, (a-b)*c, a*b+c, a*(b+c), a*b-c, a*(b-c), a*b*c]
        func1 = ["a+b+c", "a+b-c", "a+b*c", "(a+b)*c", "(a-b)+c", "a-(b+c)", "a-b-c", "a-b*c", "(a-b)*c", "a*b+c", "a*(b+c)", "a*b-c", "a*(b-c)", "a*b*c"]
        i = 0
        while i < len(func):
            dictkey = str(a)+str(b)+str(c)+ ", " +str(func1[i])
            if  not func[i] < 0 :
                self.resultsdict[dictkey] = abs(d-func[i])
                self.werte[dictkey] = func[i]
            i += 1

    def getBest(self, d, d1, d2, d3):
        self.bestresults = dict()
        keys = self.resultsdict.keys()
        minval = 1000000000
        for k in keys:
            if int(self.resultsdict[k]) <= int(minval):
                minval = int(self.resultsdict[k])
        print("THE BEST COMBINATION FOR REACHING " + str(d) + " WITH " + str(d1) + ", " + str(d2) + ", " + str(d3) + " HAS BEEN GAINED WITH REST: " + str(minval)) 
        for k in keys:
            if int(self.resultsdict[k]) == int(minval):
                ergebnis = self.werte[k]
                print('\t' + "Combination: " + str(k) + ", Result: " + str(ergebnis))   
t = Calc()
```

In func I hardcoded part of possible combinations.

Now I'm looking for an algorithm that generates these combinations automatically so I don't have to write them all down manually.

How would you do that?

Comment: Did you think about it more than 10 seconds?

Comment: Then summarise it and put it together with your tries and errors in your question.

Comment: I just edited my post with what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use

python "itertools"
http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

to genrate all combinations of `['+','-','*','a','b','c',10]`

So that you can get all possible combinations and then just filter out the valid expressions.
but it won't generate paranthesis.

You can include `['(',')']`
but it will take more time.

Comment: try doing eval within a try except to see if the expression is correct

Comment: what do you mean with "doing eval" ?